# How do I add a keyboard shortcut to open VS Code on the folder from File Explorer?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-file-explorer

I want to be able to press `.` in any folder that I'm in File Explorer and open Visual Studio Code on that folder. It is the same effect as right-clicking and clicking "Open with Code". Pressing `.` is just like I could do on the GitHub website.

It might not be officially possible, but are there any workarounds to make it work?

Comment: does this [article](https://thisdavej.com/right-click-on-windows-folder-and-open-with-visual-studio-code/) help ?

Comment: @nwpie i dont wanna right click, because that's two mouse clicks and I don't like it. i wanna just press `.` and open vscode right away.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible with AutoHotKey (and other hotkey-like programs), but are you open to installing 3rd-party programs?

Comment: @GinoMempin Sure. I'm even looking for a 3rd party file explorer because Window's one is poopy but that's off-topic. Again, as I said in my question, 
> It might not be officially possible, but are there any workarounds to make it work?
So, if any good 3rd party software works, it'd be great.

Comment: I don't think Windows Explorer allows adding custom keyboard shortcuts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you @AdrAs and @SarvinR for the answers. I used Sarvin's solution for a while, while trying to google and make sense of Adr's solution. Sarvin's solution is very useful if you're not trying to download any external programs, but if you want the true solution to this question, I finally managed it here:

Download [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com). It's good if you're familiar with it. AHK basically creates hotkeys (or shortcuts) like Adr described.

(If you have an existing ahk that you use, you can skip these steps and copy the code block down below)
Create a new AutoHotKey script by right-clicking on your desktop or anywhere in file explorer (we're gonna move it later so it doesn't matter). Name it whatever you want. I'm going to call it `MyScript.ahk` for this answer (I actually used `david.ahk` for myself).

Now, open command prompt (`win + r`, `cmd`, `enter`) and look for where VSCode is by typing `where code`. It will probably give you two lines. Take note of one of the lines (I chose the top one).
[image: cmd]

Right-click the `ahk` script file that you just created and choose `Edit Script` (or you can open it with notepad++ or VSCode or any editor of your choice, it's just a normal text file). Delete everything and paste this in:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

GetActiveExplorerPath()
{
    explorerHwnd := WinActive("ahk_class CabinetWClass")
    if (explorerHwnd)
    {
        for window in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows
        {
            if (window.hwnd==explorerHwnd)
            {
                return window.Document.Folder.Self.Path
            }
        }
    }
}

#IfWinActive ahk_exe Explorer.exe
.::
path := GetActiveExplorerPath()
run, "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code" "%path%"
return
```

On the second last line, replace the VSCode location with what you just saw in cmd. You most likely have to just change the username from `david` to your name.

Now, save the file try opening it (double click the `ahk`). If it works, a green `H` icon should appear on your tray without any errors. Go into any file directory in Windows File Explorer and hit `.` like you would normally do in GitHub. (Do Not do this in large directories like your root C:. There will be too many files for VSCode to load). It should work like expected, and if it doesn't, you did something wrong (I did the exact same thing like I just described and it works).

Now, of course, you would want to run this script on startup. Copy/Move the `.ahk` file into `C:\Windows\System32`. It will ask you for administrator permissions, so click yes. Open the registry editor (`win + r`, `regedit`, `enter`). Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`. On the right side pane, right click on the empty space then create a new String Value with any name (I used `davidAHK`) and set its value to your ahk file that you just copied/moved with quotes (`"C:\Windows\System32\david.ahk"` for my case). Close the Registry Editor and safely restart your computer. The ahk script should run on start up and you should be able to click `.` in any directory in file explorer to open VSCode.

Again, thank you @AdrAs and @SarvinR for your help!

Comment: The script does not escape spaces in the folder path. For example, if I open a folder named "New Folder" it will stop at "New" and will open an empty file in vscode called 'New'. do you know how I can fix that?

Comment: I found a solution, you can wrap the `%path%` variable with a quotation mark `"%path%"` to escape any spaces in the folder path or file name.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest issue is getting the current location from windows explorer. This requires some reverse engineering to get the memory address where windows explorer stores the location. If for any reason this address changes, you will need to find it again.

Besides that, windows supports global keyboard hooks. So you'd like to set up a global keyboard hook for your `.` key. The windows API also provides methods to get the active window. So whenever the `.` key is pressed, you can check that the active window is an explorer window. Then you'd read the current folder from the explorer window's memory. After that you've got everyting you need to start visual studio code.

This is very hacky, but I guess it's the only choice you have. Topics to research are:

- Keyloggers - These for instance use the global hooks I mentioned
- Generic reverse engineering - To find the address of the current location in windows explorer

**Edit**: [Autohotkey post](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=69925) about how to get the windows explorer location. If that works as people claim, autohotkey can also be used to register a hook for the `.` key and launch VS code.

Answer (score 1):

I have an trick for this

Create `vs.bat` and write this code in that

```
@echo off
code %cd%
```

And Move this file to `C:/Windows/System32/`

Now All Set.

If you type `vs` on the address bar of explorer your vs code with current folder will open

Answer (score 1):

I wanted launch VS Code with the open folder OR the selected files, using AHK v2, and I wanted it to be plug & play for other users. Here's the result:

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

; This is the key combo.
#!.::
{
    ; Is the current window an Explorer window?
    if (WinGetClass("A") == "CabinetWClass") {
        ; Cache the current clipboard contents.
        clipboard := A_Clipboard

        ; Clear the clipboard & copy selected files.
        A_Clipboard := ""
        Send "^c"
        ClipWait(0.5)

        ; If no files are selected...
        if (A_Clipboard == "") {
            ; Get the current window's ID.
            hwnd := WinGetID("A")

            ; Find the current window's COM object.
            for window in ComObject("Shell.Application").Windows{
                if (window && window.hwnd && window.hwnd == hwnd)
                    ; Get the current folder's path.
                    path := window.Document.Folder.Self.Path
            }
        }

        else {
            ; Quote & space-concatenate selected files.
            path := '"' . StrReplace(A_Clipboard, "`n", '" "') . '"'
        }

        ; Restore the clipboard.
        A_Clipboard := clipboard     
        
        ; Run code.
        exe := '"' . StrReplace(A_AppData, "Roaming", "Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\code") . '"'
        Run(exe . " " . path)
    }
}
```

Works like a charm, and it's a piece of cake to install & run on your machine! Instructions at [the repo](https://github.com/karmaniverous/dot-code).

Answer (score 0):

open VSCode  -> command+shift+p  -> Enter shell command – > click the prompt "shell command: install 'code' command in path"

open directory -> code .