# How to detect if the user is naming/renaming a file/folder in AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey, explorer, microsoft-file-explorer

I don't want hotkeys to fire up when [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGE6K.png) or [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnS5N.png) is happening. How can I do that?

Something I'm expecting:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe Explorer.exe

.::

if(!namingfile){

    run, "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code"

}

return

#IfWinActive
```

How do I check for `!namingfile`?

EDIT: I forgot to mention I also want it to ignore in the file address bar. I guess it should try to detect if I'm editing some text? [I'm trying to achieve this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72077329/how-do-i-add-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-open-vs-code-on-the-folder-from-file-explore)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you /u/jcunews1 for helping me! Here's the answer:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe Explorer.exe
.::
    if (focused == "Edit1") {
        controlget hwndEdit, hwnd, , %focused%, a
        hwndparent:= dllcall("GetParent", "ptr", hwndEdit, "ptr")
        wingetclass parentclass, ahk_id %hwndparent%
        isNotRenaming:= parentClass == "CtrlNotifySink"
    } else isNotRenaming:= false
    if (isNotRenaming) {
        EnvGet LocalAppData, LOCALAPPDATA
                Run % LocalAppData "\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code"
    } else {
        Send .
    }
    return

#IfWinActive
```

I tested it and it works very well like I described in the first question.